# Перенос базы с сервера

Tags: mongodb, ruby, ruby-on-rails

День добрый.
Интересует такой вопрос.
На сервере стоят рельсы работающие с `mongodb`. Каким образом я могу перенести базу к себе на локальную машину?
Была идея сделать экспорт миграций, получится ли такой вариант и если получится, то как лучше реализовать?
Сильно не пинайте =) новичек в этом вопросе... Буду благодарен за ответ!

Comment: А можно немного подробнее: что вы имеете в виду под 'экспортом миграций'?

Comment: Была идея выдернуть с сервера базу в виде миграций, но я насколько понимаю, с монго рельсы не создают никаких миграций, так и не решил как базу перенести на локальный компьютер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не имел дела с Ruby-on-Rails, но они, по сути, здесь не при чем. Для переноса базы можно использовать команду mongodb [db.copyDatabase()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/#db.copyDatabase). Последовательность действий примерно следующая:

1. Останавливаем приложение, работающее с базой
2. Запускаем на локальной машине  `mongod`
3. Подключаемся к нему и выполняем вышеуказанную команду. Формат такой: `db.copyDatabase('from_db', 'to_db', 'from_hostname')`, где `from_db` - имя копируемой базы, `to_db` - имя копии базы , `from_hostname` - сервер, откуда копируется база
4. Переконфигурируем приложение, работающее с базой, на новый источник и стартуем его

Если для подключения к базе используется аутентификация, то в вызов `db.copyDatabase()` нужно будет включить login/password. Подробнее читайте здесь: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/copy-databases-between-instances/.